# Rails Favicon not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb, favicon

I'm trying to load a favicon using a .ico file located in the public folder, but can't seem to get it working. This is what I have so far. Any ideas?

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'R9favicon.ico', :rel => 'shortcut icon' %>
```

Comment: which version of rails are you on?

Comment: What is the error? More details required for your end. Here are some of the things you can check. Do you see the link tag in generated html and is it pointing to the correct url? Are you able to fetch the ico file using a direct url like this `http://mysite/R9favicon.ico`? What permissions are there on the ico file? You have an uppercase letter in the file name, check if it works with all lowercase letters.

Comment: There is no error, just an icon that is a blank piece of paper with a folded top right corner (not the correct image). When I go to http://mysite/R9favicon.ico the correct image shows up in the browser, and changing the filename to all lower case letters doesn't work either.

Comment: What HTML does it get generated to?

Comment: `code` <link href="/assets/r9favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` helper:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb, line 166
def favicon_link_tag(source='favicon.ico', options={})
  tag('link', {
    :rel  => 'shortcut icon',
    :type => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
    :href => path_to_image(source)
  }.merge!(options.symbolize_keys))
end
```

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to Rails, what do you mean by "in helper" ?

Comment: you may also need to add this line to `application_controller.rb`: **`helper_method :favicon_link_tag`** to make the helper method available in the view layouts